# scrapy_selenium scroll multiple time in web page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-selenium

im trying to scroll more than once in same instance of webdriver using scrapy selenium .

as sending another SeleniumRequest will refresh the page.

here is my code :

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'scss'

def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll'
    yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, wait_time=5,
                          script="window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

def parse(self, response):
    quote_item = QuoteItem()
    yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, wait_time=5,
                          script="window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

also settings :

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = "/../chromedriver.exe"
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--window-size=1920,1080']

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
```